# WCF/RIA: automatically updating a WCF/RIA Service from itself

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, auto-update

I need to be able to update a wcf/RIA service that's installed on IIS. Is this at all possible?

I need to do it automatically, pretty much like the auto update of a program works.

I suppose I could call a method on the WCF service and it checks to see if there is an update but would I download and install the update?

It's because all my logic is installed in the service so I need to automatically update the service.

Answer (score 1):

Martin, I think what you are looking for is not possible in WCF RIA services.

A WCF RIA service through the code generation process has components and entities serverside and clientside in your Silverlight application. Altering the service contract on the server would cause a mismatch on the client side.

For this I think you should look beyond WCF RIA at WCF, versioning of services is a big topic in SOA, I found a link that may help get you started [here](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/versioning-wcf-services-part-i.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Rus, yes interesting topic! But if i ensure that i automatically update the RIA services and the silverlight client... then i presume this should be ok??

Comment: @Martin - In theory you should be fine. I would consider looking at MEF on the client side as I recall someone describing it for 'types you don't know at compile time'.

Comment: The client and server are deployed as a single IIS app, so you effectively just need to have a deployment process in place that pushes out the latest and greatest version to the server.  If you are using out-of-browser clients then you need to make sure it checks on run that it has the latest version using CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync.

Comment: CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync is really focused on out of browser applications where the client can check to see if a newer version is available (plus get it at the sametime). But you did make me think that using MEF client and server side you could load different satellite assemblies and XAPs.